# Remote Desktop mapped drive security

Tags: security, remote-desktop, file-transfer

I've a question that I haven't been able to find information online yet regarding the security of Remote Desktop server.  I have found the ways of securing the connection made to a Remote Desktop server via setting encryption settings and adding certificates, but I read somewhere that when you do file transfer between a remote server and your client using mapped network drive it is not secure/encrypted.  Can someone verify this?  If there is a means of securing the file transfer, could someone shed some light on this?

(Additional information: The RDP server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 in a domain that will be exposed to the internet for people to access it remotely.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, we don't have enough information on your architecture to answer.  We don't know how the servers are configured, or where your "eavesdropping" threat might be.  There are, however, lots of ways to secure the file mount. (1) Assuming you have a plain-vanilla server with MS Fileservices role installed, both it and the RDS server can be configured to require ipSec for all mounted filesystems. (2) Assuming both the fileserver and the RDS server are in the same (secure) datacenter, they can be configured to communicate over a closed network.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail (i'll also update my OP), the server is a Windows Server 2008 R2, and it will be exposed to the internet for people to access.  The eavesdropping threat could be anywhere between the internet and our network (since I am less concerned about it happening inside the network).  I think my network engineer mentioned ipSec to me, but I never found much about this.  Can you provide some information on this?  Thanks.